# How to remove element's ref after filtering it from the list

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-hooks, ref

I'm rendering an array of a 'brick' objects as a simple divs on my component.
i am also saving all the refs of the bricks with useRef, when every brick element is saved וnder it's id in a 'brickRefs' object.

under some conditions i am filtering my array so it will render less 'bricks' on the screen.

my problem is: when filtering the array, instead of removing the element i filtered from the 'brickRefs' object - i see that it's still there with a value of null;

what will be the right way to remove it completely from the ref's object ?

```
//initial ref and state: 
const bricksRef = useRef({});
const [bricks, setBricks] = useState([]);
   

  useEffect(() => {
    // initializing bricks data
    const bricksData = getBricks(NUMBER_OF_BRICKS);
    setBricks(bricksData);
}, [])

// filtering the array under some conditions :
const isHittedBrick = (nextTopPos, nextLeftPos) => {     
    const brickHitted = Object.entries(bricksRef.current).filter(([key, value]) => {
        ... returning true under some conditions
    }).map(([id]) => id)
    setBricks(bricks => bricks.filter(b => !brickHitted.includes(b.id)))
}

//render while setting all divs into the refs object:
   return (
    <section className='bricks'>
        {
            bricks.map(b => {
                return <div key={b.id} className='brick' ref={ref => bricksRef.current[b.id] = ref}>
                    {b.id}
                </div>
            })
        }
    </section>
)
```

Answer (score -1):

at the `filter`, right before `return` delete the `false` from ref object

```
const brickHitted = Object.entries(bricksRef.current).filter(([key, value]) => {
        if (false under some conditions) delete bricksRef.current[key] // if I understand correctly and b.id === key
        ... returning true under some conditions
    }).map(([id]) => id)
```

more about `delete` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete

Comment: There is no problam with mutating the refs object directly ?

Comment: Actually `bricksRef.current[b.id] = ref` is mutating directly as well :)

Comment: You are right (: the delete felt a little more hardcore haha.. thanks